# Audio stream reading function getting stuck during multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyaudio

Consider this python code:

```
class Recorder:
(...)

    def __init__(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=FORMAT,
                                  channels=CHANNELS,
                                  rate=RATE,
                                  input=True,
                                  output=True,
                                  frames_per_buffer=chunk)
    (...)
    def listen(self):
        print('Listening beginning')
        while True:
            input = self.stream.read(chunk)
            rms_val = self.rms(input)
            if rms_val > Threshold:
                self.record()


(...)

import multiprocessing

a = Recorder()

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=a.listen)
####a.listen()

while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    print("hello world")
```

The code enters "listen", prints "Listening beginning", but when executing "input = self.stream.read(chunk)", it loops infinitely  (the audio "chunk" is set to 1024).

This problem does not happen when I don't use multiprocessing, it works as expected when I run "a.listen()" instead of multiprocessing.Process .
I want the code to reach the "while True" line without waiting for the "listen" process.

How to get it working properly when using multiprocessing?

Comment: presumably it's because you're opening the device in one process and trying to read it from a different process. try moving the device opening code into the other process

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got it working.

The answer is simple.

We are not supposed to use multiprocessing in this scenario, but Threading instead:

```
import threading

a = Recorder()


thread1 = threading.Thread(target = a.listen)
thread1.start()
```

With this, the code is now working as intended.